# The sleep command executes not how i expected

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
  printf("Whats up");
  sleep(3);
  printf("StackOverflow? All having a nice day? ");
}
```

Why is the output after 3 seconds "Whats up Stack.." and not first "Whats up" and then, 3 sec later the rest?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because `stdout` is usually line-buffered. So your C library buffers the output. You can flush this by using `\n` in `printf()` or by calling [`fflush(stdout)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html).

```
  printf("Whats up\n");
```

or

```
fflush(stdout); // call after the printf
```

You can also turn off the buffering with [`setbuf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setbuf.3.html):

```
setbuf(stdout, 0);
```

Comment: As a quick note that isnt directly related to OPs question but still relevant. If your on linux using the newline character to flush the buffer will only work on the terminal and wont work on file redirection