# Sleep() in a Thread in c

Tags: c

I want my program to print

- Hello in 1st second
- Hello in 2nd second
- Hello in 3rd second.

So I have written the below code.
Whats actually happening is

- 1st second - nothing
- 2nd second - nothing
- 3rd second - HelloHelloHello

How to correct it ?

Whats actually happening is i

```
void *myThreadFun(void *vargp)
{
    while (1)
    {
        sleep(1);
        printf("hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: `printf("hello");` -----> `printf("hello\n");`

Comment: or `fflush(stdout);`

Comment: No@LPs . In 1st,2nd,3rd second I want to print Hello. But the code is printing hellohellohello in 3rd second.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The sleep command executes not how i expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34275041/the-sleep-command-executes-not-how-i-expected)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C `stdio` is **buffered** with three different modes supported:

- *unbuffered*: everything is read or written directly
- *line buffered*: data is held in the buffer until it's full or a newline is encountered
- *full buffered*: data is held in the buffer until it's full

You can always force a buffer flush with `fflush()`. So, adding `fflush(stdout)` after your `printf()` will work.

As `stdout` is *by default* in *line buffered* mode, you can also just append `\n` (a newline) to your string, the newline will trigger a buffer flush.

Comment: Thanks. But If i say printf("hi") without \n it prints wothout flushing. Why ?

Comment: Great, I was looking for this to update in the answer. Plus one from me

Comment: @AdityaJha Most likely because the program exits and the buffers are flushed on exit.

Answer (score 6):

Try this, You need to flush the stream which can be either done by `fflush` or by adding `\n`.

`printf` does not always call `write` for performance reason as system calls are costly. It rather buffers it and write at once when required. By adding, `\n` or `fflush` make the buffer to be printed on stdout everytime.

```
void *myThreadFun(void *vargp)
{
    while(1){
        printf("hello\n");
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```